# Spread an object into a table

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I'm looking for a simple (and hopefully neat) way to convert an object of this form:

```
const object = {
    key1: [a, b],
    key2: [x, y, z]
};
```

To this:

```
[key1, a, key1, b, key2, x, key2, y, key2, z]
```

What I have so far is this:

```
const table = Object.entries(object).map(entry => [entry[0], ...entry[1]]);
```

Which gives me this:

```
[key1, a, b, key2, x, y, z]
```

How can I move forward?

Comment: Got it: `const table = Object.entries(object).map(entry => entry[1].map(value => [entry[0], value]).reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, ...val], []));`.

Comment: You should post that as an answer too... it can't hurt to have multiple (that will make 4) ways to get the desired output

Comment: @Nick: I'm actually hoping to simplify that one, any idea?

Comment: There's a couple of answers that don't use `flat` that are a little more efficient I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the entries of the object using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and use a double nested [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) one mapping the entries, and the other for mapping the actual value arrays to be `[key, value]` pairs like so:

```js
const object = {
  key1: ['a', 'b'],
  key2: ['x', 'y', 'z']
};
const res = Object.entries(object).flatMap(([k, vals]) => vals.flatMap(v => [k, v]));
console.log(res);
```

Without flatMap you can use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) along with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`):

```js
const object = {
  key1: ['a', 'b'],
  key2: ['x', 'y', 'z']
};
const res = Object.entries(object).reduce(
  (acc, [key, vals]) => acc.concat(...vals.map(v => [key, v])), []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `TypeError: Object.entries(...).flatMap is not a function`

Comment: I'm using NodeJS, not a browser (which I think is the reason for the error above).

Comment: @goodvibration What version of nodejs are you using? This will work in later versions. of node

Comment: I'm using node v10.16.0.

Comment: @goodvibration ah, yeah, it is supported in 11.0.0 onwards, so if you're able to update then the above will work (we're currently on version 14 so you're a little behind :P)

Comment: Following your answer: `const table = Object.entries(object).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => [...acc, ...values.map(value => [key, value])], []);`. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the object entries, pushing a key/value pair to the accumulator for each entry in the value:

```js
const object = {
  key1: ['a', 'b'],
  key2: ['x', 'y', 'z']
};

const result = Object.entries(object)
  .reduce((c, [k, a]) => {
    a.forEach(v =>
      c.push(k, v)
    );
    return c;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

On old Node versions, you can use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and spread syntax `[].concat(...array)` to flatten arrays, using the same overall approach as [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65487646/6243352):

```js
const object = {
  key1: [1, 2],
  key2: [3, 4, 5]
};

const result = [].concat(
  ...Object.entries(object)
    .map(([k, v]) => 
      [].concat(...v.map(e => [k, e]))
    )
);
console.log(result);
```

If you flatten things often, you can make it a function and bury it in your utilities file so it reads a bit cleaner:

```js
const flat = a => [].concat(...a);
const flatMap = (a, fn) => flat(a.map(fn));

const object = {
  key1: [1, 2],
  key2: [3, 4, 5]
};

const result = flatMap(
  Object.entries(object),
  ([k, v]) => flatMap(v, e => [k, e])
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that without using flat() method. You can do that using reduce and forEach to achieve this.

```js
obj = {'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [4,5,6]};

ret = Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    obj[curr].forEach(item => { prev = [...prev, curr, item]; });
    return prev;
}, []);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried `flat` but getting `not a function` for that. I think it's not supported on NodeJS.

Comment: @goodvibration updated the code without flat()

Answer (score 1):

Method 1, Using `Object.entries`, `map` and `flat` 
Method 2, Using `Object.entries`, `forEach` and `push`

```js
const object = {
  key1: ["a", "b"],
  key2: ["x", "y", "z"],
};

// Method 1, Using Object.entries, map and flat
const res = Object.entries(object)
  .map(([key, arr]) => arr.map((value) => [key, value]))
  .flat(2);

// Method 2, Using Object.entries, forEach and push
const toArr = (obj) => {
  const res = [];
  Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, arr]) =>
    arr.forEach((value) => res.push(key, value))
  );
  return res;
};

console.log(res)
console.log(toArr(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

using map and flat() you can achieve the result

```
const object = {
    key1: ['a', 'b'],
    key2: ['x', 'y', 'z']
};


Object.keys(object).map((e, i )=> { 
    return Object.values(object[e]).map( v => { return [e, v]}).flat()
}).flat()
// ["key1", "a", "key1", "b", "key2", "x", "key2", "y", "key2", "z"]
```

Comment: You can eliminate all of the nested `flat` calls by using `flat(2)` in one call at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The most concise, clean and elegant way would be to combine Object.entries() and flat() with a degree sent as a parameter to the flat method.

Note: flat()- works on an array and flattens the array to the degree sent in the params. It returns a new flatten array. For example:

```
let arr = [1, 2, [3]];
let arrDegree1 = arr.flat();
console.log(arrDegree1) //[1,2,3];

let arr2 = [1, 2, [[3]]]
let arrDegreeTwo = arr2.flat(2);
console.log(arrDegreeTwo) //[1,2,3];
```

Thus Solution for this would be:

```
const o = {
  key1: ['a', 'b'],
  key2: ['x', 'y', 'z']
};

const result = Object.entries(o).reduce((acc,[key, values])=>{
  return [...acc, (values.map(v=> [key,...v])) ];
},[]).flat(2);

console.log("Result",result);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Have amended the code!